# AWS Segments cannot be called as AmazonPinpointClientBuilder cannot be imported

Tags: android, amazon-web-services

I cannot import the AmazonPinpointClientBuilder class for making calls to segments
Using the following compile statements on Android:
compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-pinpoint:2.6.19'
compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-sns:2.6.19'

Answer (score 0):

`AmazonPinpointClientBuilder` is present in AWS Java SDK but not in AWS Android SDK. The AWS Android SDK for `Pinpoint` providers `AmazonPinpointClient` class and object construction through constructors only.

**AWS Android SDK**: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-android/blob/master/aws-android-sdk-pinpoint/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/services/pinpoint/AmazonPinpointClient.java#L88

**AWS Java SDK**: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blob/master/aws-java-sdk-pinpoint/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/services/pinpoint/AmazonPinpointClientBuilder.java

Comment: How can I add the amazon-java-sdk dependency on Android?

Comment: @abhishek https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/setup-install.html